# AngularJS Not Updating UI With SignalR

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, signalr

So this angularjs code is not updating the UI when I place it inside signalR function. I even use `$scope.$apply()` to force digest.

This is my code:

```
var notificationHub = $.connection.progressNotificationHub;
notificationHub.client.displayAdminNotification = function (currentProgress, totalProgress, msg, finish) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        if ($scope.adminNotification == null)
            $scope.adminNotification = {};

        $scope.adminNotification.currentProgress = currentProgress;
        $scope.adminNotification.totalProgress = totalProgress;
        $scope.adminNotification.msg = msg;
        $scope.adminNotification.percentage = totalProgress == 0 ? 0 : (currentProgress / totalProgress) * 100;
        $scope.adminNotification.finish = finish;

        if (finish) {
            $scope.adminNotification = null;
        }
    })
};

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
});
```

And this is my UI:

```
<!-- Notification -->
<div class="admin-notification-container" ng-show="adminNotification != null && showAdminNotification">
    <div class="dark-overlay" style="opacity:0.9"></div>
    <div class="admin-notification-content">
        <div class="admin-notification-progress">
            <p>Progress: {{adminNotification.currentProgress}} of {{adminNotification.totalProgress}}</p>
            <div class="admin-notification-progress-bar-container">
                <div class="admin-notification-progress-bar progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" style="width:{{adminNotification.percentage}}%">{{adminNotification.percentage}}%</div>
            </div>
            <p class="admin-notification-msg">{{adminNotification.msg}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide-admin-notification" ng-click="toggleAdminNotification()">-</div>
</div>

<div ng-show="adminNotification != null && !showAdminNotification" class="hide-admin-notification-hide" ng-click="toggleAdminNotification()">^</div>
```

---

### Update

After further investigation. When my webapi server send a message to the UI, the '$scope' used inside the `displayAdminNotification` function is not the same as the declared `$scope`. It declares a new `$scope` and use it.

Why is this happening?

Comment: can you publish an example to the net? signalr cant be 'guessed' sometimes.

did you try to use simple setTimeout for testcase?

Comment: does `displayAdminNotification`  fired ?

Comment: What is weird is that the `$scope` looks like a separate instance from the declared `$scope`. It has all the functions, but all variables / instances that was declared and assigned from the page initiation do not exist. It seems the `$scope` used by the signalr code is initialized in a different instance.

Comment: @Aria yes it is fired.

Comment: Please show us the whole controller

Comment: Also did you try the controller as vm instead of $scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem is my controller is fired twice. This is because I have nested controllers.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    ......
        <div ng-app="anotherApp" ng-controller="controller"></div>
</div>
```

And I use controller that extends another controller. Something like this:

```
app.controller('ctrl', adminController);

adminController.$inject = ["$scope", "$controller", "$http", '$sce'];

function adminController ($scope, $controller, $http, $sce)
{
    angular.extend(this, $controller('controller', { $scope: $scope }));
    .....
```

For whoever got the problem like this, please check your controller structure.